# ReactJS. Quite slow when rendering and updating a simple list of 1500 <li> elements. I thought VirtualDOM was fast

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, reactjs

I was really disappointed by the performance I got on the following simple ReactJS example. When clicking on an item, the label (count) gets updated accordingly. Unfortunately, this takes roughly ~0.5-1 second to get updated. That's mainly due to "re-rendering" the entire todo list.

My understanding is that React's key design decision is to make the API seem like it re-renders the whole app on every update. It is supposed take the current state of the DOM and compare it with the target DOM representation, do a diff and update only the things that need to get updated.

Am I doing something which is not optimal? I could always update the count label manually (and the state silently) and that will be an almost instant operation but that takes away the point of using ReactJS.

```js
/** @jsx React.DOM */

TodoItem = React.createClass({

    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            completedCallback: function () {
                console.log('not callback provided');
            }
        };
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return this.props;
    },

    updateCompletedState: function () {
        var isCompleted = !this.state.data.completed;
        this.setState(_.extend(this.state.data, {
            completed: isCompleted
        }));
        this.props.completedCallback(isCompleted);
    },

    render: function () {
        var renderContext = this.state.data ?
            (<li className={'todo-item' + (this.state.data.completed ? ' ' + 'strike-through' : '')}>
                <input onClick={this.updateCompletedState} type="checkbox" checked={this.state.data.completed ? 'checked' : ''} />
                <span onClick={this.updateCompletedState} className="description">{this.state.data.description}</span>
            </li>) : null;

        return renderContext;
    }
});


var TodoList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            todoItems: this.props.data.todoItems,
            completedTodoItemsCount: 0
        };
    },

    updateCount: function (isCompleted) {
        this.setState(_.extend(this.state, {
            completedTodoItemsCount: isCompleted ? this.state.completedTodoItemsCount + 1 : this.state.completedTodoItemsCount - 1
        }));
    },
    
    render: function () {
        var updateCount = this.updateCount;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>count: {this.state.completedTodoItemsCount}</div>
                <ul className="todo-list">
                    { this.state.todoItems.map(function (todoItem) {
                        return <TodoItem data={ todoItem } completedCallback={ updateCount } />
                    }) }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var data = {todoItems: []}, i = 0;

while(i++ < 1000) {
 data.todoItems.push({description: 'Comment ' + i, completed: false});
}

React.renderComponent(<TodoList data={ data } />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="http://fb.me/react-js-fiddle-integration.js"></script>
```

<sub>jsFiddle link, just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/9nrnz1qm/3/</sub>

Comment: I get 0.13s with the production build, [any better for you?](http://jsfiddle.net/rqsjvuj5/).  Diffing 4500 elements takes some time.  The only good solutions here involve not rendering 1500 TodoItems, when you can only see 100 at most :-)

Comment: How do you check the performance (i.e. you got 0.13s)?

Comment: I used the profiler in dev tools.  It shows you a timeline of all JS execution (make sure it's in Chart mode, not Heavy or Tree).  After clicking a checkbox there was about 130ms of code execution.  See my answer, it actually went down quite a bit.

Comment: Yeap.. mine is around 150-170ms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do the following, you can cut the time down by a lot.  It spends 25ms to 45ms to update for me.

- use the production build
- implement shouldComponentUpdate
- update the state immutably

```js
updateCompletedState: function (event) {
    var isCompleted = event.target.checked;
    this.setState({data: 
        _.extend({}, this.state.data, {
            completed: isCompleted
       })
    });
    this.props.completedCallback(isCompleted);
},

shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState){
    return nextState.data.completed !== this.state.data.completed;
},
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znb9w5mc/)

<sub>(there are a lot of questionable things about this code, daniula points out some of them)</sub>

Comment: So this actually means that when the TodoList is 're-rendered' a TodoItem will not get 're-rendered' if its state doesn't change?

Comment: Correct.  Which means react doesn't need to call TodoItem's render, or diff the li, input, and span when the parent updates.

Comment: This means that if the TodoItem has more than one state, i.e. completed, partially completed, etc. and a different style is applied for those, we will have to check to check all states within the shouldComponentUpdate function. Isn't this something which would have been ideal for React to automatically check?

Comment: Yes, or you could do a shallow comparison if the next state and current state objects.  React provides a [pure render mixin](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) to implement that kind of shouldComponentUpdate, but it's not enabled by default, and it compares both props and state shallowly, which will give worse performance here (not a problem when you're not rendering 1500 components!).

Comment: You could also use FixedDataTable so that it's never really creating more components than you can see on screen: https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/

Answer (score 6):

1. When you are generating list of elements you should provide unique key prop for everyone. In your case:

   ```
   <ul className="todo-list">
       { this.state.todoItems.map(function (todoItem, i) {
           return <TodoItem key={i} data={ todoItem } completedCallback={ updateCount } />
       }) }
   </ul>
   ```

   You can find out about this mistake by warning message in browser console:

   > Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of TodoList. See [fb.me/react-warning-keys](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) for more information.
2. There is another warning which you can easily fix by changing event handler on `<input type="checkbox" />` inside `<TodoItem />` from `onClick` to `onChange`:

   ```
   <input onClick={this.updateCompletedState} type="checkbox" checked={this.state.data.completed ? 'checked' : ''} />
   ```
3. You are doing some string concatenation to set proper `className`. For more readable code try using nice and simple [React.addons.classSet](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html):

   ```
   render: function () {
       var renderContext = this.state.data ?
           var cx = React.addons.classSet({
               'todo-item': true,
               'strike-through': this.state.data.completed
           });

           (<li className={ cx }>
               <input onChange={this.updateCompletedState} type="checkbox" checked={this.state.data.completed ? 'checked' : ''} />
               <span onClick={this.updateCompletedState} className="description">{this.state.data.description}</span>
           </li>) : null;

       return renderContext;
   }
   ```

Comment: Also `checked={this.state.data.completed}`, the checked prop is a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at where you render() the list...

```
<div>
   <div>count: {this.state.completedTodoItemsCount}</div>
   <ul className="todo-list">
        { this.state.todoItems.map(function (todoItem) {
            return <TodoItem data={ todoItem } completedCallback={ updateCount } />
        }) }
   </ul>
</div>
```

This should not be called every time a TodoItem is updated.  Give the above element a surrounding `div` and an `id` like this:

```
return <div id={someindex++}><TodoItem
  data={ todoItem }
  completedCallback={ updateCount }
/></div>
```

Then simply rerender a single TodoItem as it is changed, like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(<TodoItem ...>, document.getElementById('someindex'));
```

ReactJS is supposed to be fast, yes, but you still need to stick to general programming paradigms, i.e., asking the machine to do as little as possible, thereby producing the result as fast as possible.  Rerendering stuff that doesn't need to get re-rendered gets in the way of that, whether or not it's "best practice".

Comment: ...or just add the key prop on the component, right? I'd really like to know what's best.